# How do I detect duplicates subnodes with several nodes with XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

How can I find duplicate subnodes with XQuery and/or XPath, my XML structure looks like this:

```
<register>
  <operator referenceid="1">
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_code</type>
      <name>101010</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_text</type>
          <name>Accounting</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Big_code</type>
      <name>1</name>
    </operationpart>
  </operator>
  <operator referenceid="2">
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_code</type>
      <name>202020</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_text</type>
      <name>Development</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Big_code</type>
      <name>2</name>
    </operationpart>
  </operator>
  <operator referenceid="3">
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_code</type>
      <name>101010</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_text</type>
      <name>Accounting</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Big_code</type>
      <name>1</name>
    </operationpart>
  </operator>
  <operator referenceid="4">
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_code</type>
      <name>101010</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_text</type>
      <name>Accounting</name>
    </operationpart>
  </operator>
  <operator referenceid="5">
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_code</type>
      <name>101010</name>
    </operationpart>
    <operationpart>
      <type>Category_text</type>
      <name>Accounting</name>
    </operationpart>
  </operator>
</register>
```

Two should get listed in a result as duplicates, that is 4 and 5, also 1 and 3.

XQuery/Xpath should also ignore the attribute referenceid which always must be unique in the XML-list.

Comment: it is not quite clear what counts as a duplicate subnode from your question. Could you add a sample of the output that you wish to generate. You can probably remove elements with referenceid 4 and 5 from your input sample, to make things more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @duncdrum, the example should be clear, but I can result I wanna get produced after looking for duplicates.  
referenceid 4, referenceid 5  
referenceid 1, referenceid 3  
  
I wanna detect a combination of elements which are duplicates, wanna compare in the level <operator> and detect if other <operator> content are the same except for the attribute which always are unique.

Comment: I do not wanna remove, I wanna see what is duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to put this in a list; how about showing the duplicate nodes:

```
/register/*
   [normalize-space(.) = preceding-sibling::*/normalize-space(.)
  and
    not(normalize-space(.) = following-sibling::*/normalize-space(.))
   ]
```

[Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cregister%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%221%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E1%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%222%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E202020%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EDevelopment%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E2%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%223%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E1%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%224%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%225%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%3C%2Fregister%3E&=&extract=%2Fregister%2F*%0A%20%20%20%5Bnormalize-space(.)%20%3D%20preceding-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.)%0A%20%20and%0A%20%20%20%20not(normalize-space(.)%20%3D%20following-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.))%0A%20%20%20%5D&=&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2), which returns the node with `referenceid` 3 and 5.

or the opposite, to return 1 and 4:

```
/register/*
   [normalize-space(.) = following-sibling::*/normalize-space(.)
  and
    not(normalize-space(.) = preceding-sibling::*/normalize-space(.))
   ]
```

If needed, you can [combine both](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cregister%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%221%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E1%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%222%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E202020%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EDevelopment%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E2%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%223%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3EBig_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E1%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%224%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%20%20%3Coperator%20referenceid%3D%225%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_code%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E101010%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctype%3ECategory_text%3C%2Ftype%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3EAccounting%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Foperationpart%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Foperator%3E%0A%3C%2Fregister%3E&=&extract=%2Fregister%2F*%0A%20%20%20%5Bnormalize-space(.)%20%3D%20preceding-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.)%0A%20%20and%0A%20%20%20%20not(normalize-space(.)%20%3D%20following-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.))%0A%20%20%20%5D%0A%7C%0A%2Fregister%2F*%0A%20%20%20%5Bnormalize-space(.)%20%3D%20following-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.)%0A%20%20and%0A%20%20%20%20not(normalize-space(.)%20%3D%20preceding-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.))%0A%20%20%20%5D&=%2Fregister%2F*%0A%20%20%20%5Bnormalize-space(.)%20%3D%20following-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.)%0A%20%20and%0A%20%20%20%20not(normalize-space(.)%20%3D%20preceding-sibling%3A%3A*%2Fnormalize-space(.))%0A%20%20%20%5D&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2) with an `|` operator.
It's up to you. Obviously, this case can be further simplified.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wp78de, looks promising, is it possible to show all duplicates lines in the result?  Like not only referenceid 3 and 5 but also which they duplicates like 1,3 and 4,5 so I get a complete list what duplicates? Also is it possible also to make this with XQuery?

Comment: I also tried to add more duplicates with same values and this only shows the last duplicate, little tough to detect all duplicates if I always only see the last duplicates and not everyone